# Find all possible permutations of removing given char from a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a script that will generate all possible texts by deleting any number of spaces between words of a given sentence:

Example:

Original sentence:

> I want to delete spaces

Expected output:

> ```
> I want to delete spaces
>
> Iwant to delete spaces
>
> Iwant todeletespaces
>
> Iwanttodelete spaces
>
> Iwanttodeletespaces
> ```
>
> etc.

Comment: Your algorithm only makes for first spaces. I want make it for like my sample all of them. You took first spaces as a reference but also needed others. Like I want deletespaces.Check it out my sample well and you will understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html).

We create a list of words, then join them with all possible combinations of `''` (empty string) or `' '` (space):

```
from itertools import product, zip_longest

s = 'I want to delete spaces'
words = s.split()

for separators in product((' ', ''), repeat=len(words)-1):
    print(''.join(word+separator for word, separator in zip_longest(words, separators, fillvalue='')))
```

Output:

```
I want to delete spaces
I want to deletespaces
I want todelete spaces
I want todeletespaces
I wantto delete spaces
I wantto deletespaces
I wanttodelete spaces
I wanttodeletespaces
Iwant to delete spaces
Iwant to deletespaces
Iwant todelete spaces
Iwant todeletespaces
Iwantto delete spaces
Iwantto deletespaces
Iwanttodelete spaces
Iwanttodeletespaces
```

As there is one more word than separators, we use `zip_longest` with a `fillvalue=''` in order to have an empty string as separator after the last word.

Comment: This is how I understood the requirement too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`:

```
s = 'I want delete spaces'
while ' ' in s:
    ind = s.find(' ')
    s = s[:ind] + s[ind+1:]
    print(s)

I want delete spaces
Iwant delete spaces
Iwantdelete spaces
Iwantdeletespaces
```

and so on.

Comment: Its only for one.Its okay but I want for every space like my sample

Comment: I understood your example to mean you only want to remove the first one each time the script is run. Do you want it to just remove all spaces in your string?

Comment: No its not first every combination I will give extra sample for you understand it

Comment: As far as I understand he wants a list of all the possible outcomes from removing `x` amount of spaces. So for the example 'This the example' you would get: `['This the example', 'Thisthe example', This theexample', 'Thistheexample']` Unfortunately I'm not inclined to write code for someone who says 'I want code' and nothing more.

Comment: I never told I want directly code . My algorithm was bad enough that is why I wrote here for better coding thanks for comment anyway @MattB.